# Seeded random number generator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random

What is the best seeded random number generator on ObjC?

I have to generate the same random number sequences on 2 different iPhones, therefore it has to be seeded. This is why I can't use `arc4rand()`.

NOTE: by best I mean fastest/most unpredictable relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mersenne Twister implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) that comes with the C++ standard library is very good. As it's C++, you'll need to create a wrapper so that you can call it from C and ObjC code, or alternatively rename the file that uses it to have a .mm (Objective-C++) extension.

I'm thinking of something like this, in the header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct rng_state;
struct rng_state* create_rng(unsigned seed);
void destroy_rng(struct rng_state* rng);
unsigned long long rng_random_unsigned(struct rng_state* rng, unsigned long long max);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And then, in a .cpp file that includes the above:

```
#include <random>
struct rng_state
{
  std::mt19937* rng;
};
struct rng_state* create_rng(unsigned seed)
{
  std::mt19937* engine = new std::mt19937(seed);
  rng_state* state = new rng_state;
  state->rng = engine;
}
void destroy_rng(struct rng_state* rng)
{
  delete rng->rng;
  delete rng;
}
unsigned long long rng_random_unsigned(struct rng_state* rng, unsigned long long max)
{
  std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> distribution(0, max);
  return distribution(*rng->rng);
}
```

I haven't tested the above, but it should be pretty close. You can then include the header in your C/ObjC files as usual, create a rng with a seed, get a bunch of random numbers, and destroy the rng when you're done. You can also add more generator functions if needed - the library comes with different random distributions you can use.

Comment: Why should I use and extern library? Isn't there anything in ObjC? what about srand and rand?

Comment: Sure, you can use srand and rand. However, they rely on global state, so if anything else calls `rand()` (or `srand()`) it'll interfere with your sequence. There's also no guarantee that it'll generate the same sequence on different OS versions (although that's a small risk). I'm not sure by what definition the C++ standard library is "external" - it ships with the OS/development environment.